# Winforms UserControl shows rectangles with Inverted Colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

In a Winforms application (C#2, FX2.0, VC2008) I am using a Panel derived Control to display custom controls. The controls are arranged vertically and there are usually more than fit in the visible area of the panel.

I have drawn a litte sketch of it:

[Panel http://www.ericschaefer.org/Panel.png](http://www.ericschaefer.org/Panel.png)

Sometimes (usually after scrolling inside the panel) rectangular areas appear to have their colors inverted (green part in sketch). These areas are random in size but seem always to be at the right edge of the panel. As you can see in the sketch the arrow buttons of the panels scrollbar are also inverted, but not the thumbslider and the scroll area.

By inverted colors I mean black becomes white, white becomes black, blue becomes brown, etc...

I am out of ideas.

- Can this be caused by my application?
- Is it even possible to draw into the scrollbar arrow buttons?
- Any ideas?

**EDIT**: "[Screenshot](http://www.ericschaefer.org/Foto119.jpg)"

**EDIT**: I was wrong about the Panel. It has been a Panel in the past but it is now a UserControl. Like this:

```
public class MyPanel : UserControl
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        VScroll = true;
        HScroll = false;
        AutoScroll = true;
        AutoScrollMargin = new Size( 0, 4 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of the application in this state? It might make it a bit easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Could you do a print screen rather than a photo? It's still very hard to see what's happening.

Comment: This problem occours randomly and very rare. Also it does not happen on my machines. All I have is the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**
Apparently it was the fault of the touch screen driver. I can now reproduce the behaviour. If you click the "scroll down" button on any scroll bar via touch screen and hold it down for a while it keeps scrolling when you release it (the button stays pushed). After that you can click whereever you want, there will always be the "inverted colors" on the left side of the scroll bar. It happens with any application (explorer.exe!). Now it gets even better: Generally in Windows if you drag a scroll bar thumb button you can drift off of the scroll bar if you keep the mouse button pressed. But if you drift away too far the button will snap back to its original position (where you started dragging). Try it! The inverted colors rectangles are exactly as wide as the area where you can drift off without the button snapping back. I don't even try to understand this.
We installed a newer driver for the touch screen which does not keep scrolling even after you released the "scroll down" button and the issue disappeared. My blood pressure is back to normal but all the grey hair is probably not turning black I guess...
Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the System.Windows.Forms.Panel ? What did you meant when u said Panel derived control ?

If you are using System.Windows.Forms.Panel then, this looks like a problem with the custom control and not the panel.

could you provide more info on the custom control, if possible ?

Comment: Its a custom control derived from S.W.F.Panel. All it does is placing the subcontrols (also custom controls) inside itself. There is no drawing done in the Panel, besides setting BackColor.

Comment: Looks like the doublebuffering has some problems, but not able to exactly point to the problem it might come up with.

Answer (score 1):

From your photo it looks like something's highlighted, but the border doesn't match up with any visible controls.

Have you got an control that's hidden behind the rest somehow?

Comment: No, there is no hidden control. The actual size of the area differs.  It has been reported to be much larger and also much smaller than in the photo. As shown in the sketch, there have also been two of these areas at the same time.